# Find all values of $a\in (0,\infty)$ such that $a^x=2x+1$ has only one real solution.

Tags: calculus, real-numbers

Find all values of $a\in (0,\infty)$ such that 
$a^x=2x+1$
has only one real solution.
I tried using derivatives, but I couldn't find out. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: This is very similar to [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956328/finding-all-positive-a-such-that-ax-2x1-has-only-one-real-solution).  Why not study the arguments people showed you for that one?  Maybe they apply here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. The equation $a^x=2x+1$ has at least the solution $x=0$.

i) If $0<a\leq 1$ then $a^x$ is decreasing and $2x+1$ strictly increasing and therefore the solution is unique.

ii) If $a>1$ then $a^x$ is strictly convex and we have just one solution if and only if the line $y=2x+1$ is tangent to the graph of $a^x$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Define $$f(x)=\frac{\ln(2x+1)}{\ln(a)}-x$$ and use calculus.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Plot (approximatelly,the plot doesn't really need to be particularly precise) the functions $a^x$ and $2x+1$ for the following values of $a$:

- $a=\frac12$
- $a=\frac13$
- $a=\frac14$
- $a=1$
- $a=2$
- $a=3$
- $a=4$

Can you notice a pattern?

*Subhint*:

When plotting, you only really need to be careful about:

1. What happens to the functions at $x\to-\infty$
2. What happens to the functions around $x=0$
3. What happens to the functions at $x\to\infty$